# Entity Framework Core: how to 'wipe and replace' bridge table?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Imagine we have a many-to-many relationship (e.g. `Product` and `Category` where one product can be in many categories and vice versa). They are identified through a composite key (`ProductId` / `CategoryId`).  How do we update this bridge table in Entity Framework Core when we want to persist the changes to the `Product` aggregate?

In Entity Framework 6, I'd simply wipe out all related data for that product in the bridge table and then re-populate them. This simplifies life as we don't need to manually synchronize changes (inserts, updates, deletes).  Just wipe and replace.

How do we do this in Entity Framework Core?  Here's what I tried:

```
context.ProductCategories.RemoveRange(product.Categories);
context.ProductCategories.AddRange(updatedProductCategories);
```

This results in an exception due to duplicate composite key:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ProductCategory' cannot be tracked because another instance of this
>   type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new
>   entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be
>   created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the
>   default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values
>   for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or
>   temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching
>   existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
>   key value is attached to the context.

How do we remove a composite key entity from the context so that we can add another one?

The only way I got this to work so far is to synchronize all changes (deletes, updates, inserts), but it would be much simpler to just wipe and replace.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to also set product.Categories = updatedProductCategories; ?   Not 100% sure as I don't generally ever get into a situation where I want to wipe many-manys... You'd need to potentially consider any of the Categories from the original product that might be loaded in the context at the time as well.

Comment: @StevePy I don't think it's necessary, as the context should map related entities. The sample code above works for one-to-many relationships with single column keys, just not when there are composite keys.

Comment: Have you looked at the new TrackGraph API: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/303/entity-framework-core-trackgraph-for-disconnected-data ?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the EntityState.Detached? By this you can "clear" the context tracker from the list you want to update something like:
context.Entry(yourlist).State = EntityState.Detached;
And then you can perform your AddRange